# FTP_NLIST retorna directorios en vez de archivos

Tags: php

tengo problema con esta función en particular.
Y quería ver si era algo de la función antes de hacer un workaround con otras funciones.
en la pag. muestran que los resultados deberían ser de este modo:

```
array(3) {
[0]=>
string(11) "public_html"
[1]=>
string(10) "public_ftp"
[2]=>
string(3) "www"
```

Pero en vez de eso, estoy recibiendo esto:

```
array(3) {
[0]=>
string(11) "ruta/completa/public_html"
[1]=>
string(10) "ruta/completa/public_ftp"
[2]=>
string(3) "ruta/completa/www"
```

Hay algo que cambio o algo mas que deba corregir ???

```
$cpdf = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "/php/boleta/10055704-5/pdf/");
for ($p = 0; $p < count($cpdf); $p++) {
    echo $cpdf[$p];
    echo "</br>";
}
exit;
```

Comment: No es necesario por que no obtendrás nada de eso. Esto es algo de la función. Incluso el problema está descrito en la pág. de la documentación, solo que no mencionan soluciones.

Comment: Agregue el código para que lo puedas ver...

Comment: ¿Que versión de PHP estas usando y que sistema operativo tiene servidor al que te estas conectando?

Comment: Eeeeeeso es lo que busco... han cambiado el servidor, por lo que es razonable que la versión del servidor sea otra. La de desarrollo es la 7.3.10 revisaré la del servidor ahora.

Comment: Encontré que el problema era el cambio de SO. Y solo hubo que hacer un workaround...

Comment: Me alegro que hayas encontrado la solución. Recorda que podes responder a tu pregunta y después de unas horas vas a poder marcara como aceptada. PD: no estoy seguro que que solución alterna aplicaste, pero `basename` es un buen candidato. Saludos!

Comment: Técnicamente no es solución, es una alternativa... por eso no haré respuesta.